# TextInputEditText has no 'setStartIconDrawable' function, why?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I'm playing around with `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout`, trying features and material design.

**I have**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

**In gradle,**

**and in code:**

```
    //Cannot resolve method 'setStartIconDrawable(int)
    textInputLayout.setStartIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close);
```

In fact there are **a lot of other functions missing from "my" TextInputLayout.**

What the hell is this?

I've checked there is no newer version from material lib, only alpha builds.

Answer (score 2):

With     `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'`

it is working.

It is strange that you are forced to use an alpha build to use a feature from the guidelines...